# Exception when deleting an object

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

When I try to delete an object, I get a 'System.InvalidOperationException' with the following additional information:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.

How can I get more information? This message is like "something's wrong, but we are not going to reveal what"

Answer (score 0):

The object/row you've tried to delete is probably a foreign key - the foreign key can't be null in the related table. Try deleting the other object/row first.

This issue would also happen if you tried to do this in SQL, you'd get:

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint 'FK_foo_bar'. The conflict occured in database...
```

Comment: I dont get a message like yours. Where can I get this message from?

Comment: If you delete the row directly in SQL I think you'll get that error message. You won't get it with EF.